# Using Csv file for regression

Tags: python

I am try to learn regression through CSV file I am getting the following error :

```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-36-ca92008c8d98> in <module>
>       7     for line in f:
>       8         line=line.strip().split(',')
> ----> 9         data['Username'].append(float(line[0]))
>      10 
>      11 
> 
> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

My code is

```
for header in ["Username","Identifier","First name","Last name"]:
    data[header]=[]

with open('username.csv','r') as f:
    next(f)

    for line in f:
        line=line.strip().split(',')
        data['Username'].append(float(line[0]))
```

and my CSV file looks like this

```
Username, Identifier,First name,Last name
112,9012,2,3.223 
123,2070,0.8276,3.098
876,4081,567,4.34
56,9346,789,3.78
5,507,9678,2.789
```

Comment: Why dont you import pandas and use a simpler pandas.read_csv('filepath') ? You will probably will end up importing pandas for data wrangling.

Comment: add `print(line[0])` after the line `line=line.strip().split(',')`

Comment: thankyou @balderman

Comment: @PraveenChaitanya I do not understand your last comment.

Comment: I have more lines like identifier ,first name,last name. if I use **print(line[0])**, **print(line[1])** so on . i am getting the following error 'IndexError: list index out of range' @balderman

Comment: so print the line number only - it will point to the problematic line

Comment: I did not understand your comment @balderman

Comment: @balderman if I understood the error is on 'print(line[1])'

Comment: ` for idx,line in enumerate(f): print(idx)` - this will print the line number and you will be able to understand which line throws the exception